# jquery how to show a table row based on an html5 attribute of a checked checkbox

Tags: jquery

Hi say I have the following html:

```
<input type-checkbox data-testid=@Model.TestDtos[i].Id />

<table>
  @for(var i=0; i < @Model.TestDtos[i].Count; i++)
  {
    <tr class="hidden" data-testid=@Model.TestDtos[i].Id>Show some stuff</tr>
  }
</table>
```

So I'm wanting to make it that when the checkbox with matching data-testid value is checked the table row becomes visible.

I tried:

```
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

        var testid = $(this).data('testid');
        $("tr[data-testid=testid").show();
    }
```

The problem is the IDE is saying that testid is never used. I'm unsure how to get the value from the checkbox data-testid and use it to find the correct row to show.

Comment: i think you want to remove the class `hidden`, not just use show() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`testid` is a variable, so you need to use string concatenation here

```
$('tr[data-testid="' + testid + '"]').show()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pLbdC/)

But what you really need might be

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){
    var fn = this.checked ? 'show' : 'hide';
    var testid = $(this).data('testid');
    $('tr[data-testid="' + testid + '"]')[fn]();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pLbdC/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use string concatenation to use your variable. You are also missing a square bracket from the end of the selector. Try this:

```
$("tr[data-id='"+testid+"']").show();
```